# Psychological and Sociological Researches on Teaching

Tags: reference-request

Teaching is a social activity and very sensitive to any change in social parameters. Even the simplest acts of a teacher could cause some positive/negative reactions of students and conversely. Each one of us has his own *personal experiences* in possible good and bad teaching styles and we are sharing them here in the forum. It is very helpful for us. Also the *scientific analysis* of the academic teaching done by professional sociologists and psychologists could be very useful too.

**Question.** What are good references for researches about the best teaching styles done by psychologists/sociologists?

Comment: It looks like this question is too broad a topic fro this site. You might consider some of [these tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185482/1438) for asking a more focused question.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://teachpsych.org/ebooks/asle2014/index.php) is a link to the new (free) e-book *Applying Science of Learning in Education: Infusing Psychological Science Into the Curriculum*, edited by Victor A. Benassi, Catherine E. Overson, and Christopher M. Hakala, which I haven't read yet but intend to.

Comment: Very nice reference. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

The National Research Council has two (free!) books that are worth checking out.

1. ["How People Learn"](http://www.nap.edu/openbook.php?isbn=0309070368)
2. ["How Students Learn: Mathematics in the Classroom"](http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=11101)

I'd also recommend going beyond what psychologists and sociologists have found about teaching math. Psychologists especially are going to end up with somewhat reductive pictures, and a human activity as complex as learning or teaching also benefits from a holistic approach. There's some excellent research done, for instance, on how students learn relatively elementary concepts such as fractions and multiplication. I am a huge fan of the "Cognitively Guided Instruction" series, personally.